# editable.getSpans is returning a StyleSpan, even when there isn't any style rendered on screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I am writing a `RichTextEditor` class, which has an inner `RichTextEditorTextWatcher` class. I am seeing a discrepancy from what I see on the screen, versus what I get when I call `e.getSpans` inside `beforeTextChanged`.

On the screen, I see text on the screen (in my case, a single character) that does not have any style applied to it, but the `e.getSpans()` call actually says that I have a bold style applied.

Is this a known Android bug?

```
public class RichTextEditor extends AppCompatEditText  
{

    // other code not shown

    public class RichTextEditorTextWatcher implements TextWatcher
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            if (after == 0) //deletion occurred
            {
                isDeletion = true;
                Editable e = RichTextEditor.this.getText();

                /** The next line is the problematic line!
                  * this.prevStyles returns a StyleSpan (bold) even when I don't see it on the screen for that character.
                  */
                this.prevStyles = e.getSpans(start, start+count, CharacterStyle.class); 

                for (CharacterStyle c : this.prevStyles)
                {
                    if (c instanceof StyleSpan)
                    {
                        if (((StyleSpan)c).getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD) 
                            boldButton.setChecked(true);
                        else
                            boldButton.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                isDeletion = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `TextUtils#dumpSpans()` say?

Comment: Hey @pskink. I'm using `TextUtils#dumpSpans()` now, it helps! Seems like I need to perform `e.removeSpan(currSpan)` and apply it to a shortened (with the deletion) span since the span is persisting.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean, but hey, it's good it helps!